How to see sub-items of startup programs on Mac OS X Sonoma 14?
I can see a list of startup programs by navigating to " System Settings > General > Login Items" although cannot see the sub-items of the programs.
Some of the items in the list are named by the parent company and not the specific name of the application. How can I see the names of the sub-items to determine if I want them enabled or not?


The two examples you show are of background tasks which will automatically be started or enabled at login. Those tasks support the operation of applications you have installed - in these examples, from Adobe and Barco.
In most cases you want these to be running and would only need to remove them when uninstalling the relevant application.  I must admit I get seriously annoyed about the quantity and purpose of some of the Adobe background tasks!
The naming of these "Allow in the Background" tasks causes endless confusion and worry. The names are the those of the organisation, product or person identified in the signing certificate associated with the application. These can be hard to track down.
There is no easy way of discovering what the 'sub-items' do or how to control them.
Having said it won't be easy, you can explore background tasks using either Lingon X or LaunchControl. I strongly recommend not modifying any of the tasks unless you need to and are very confident that you have the required understanding.
In principle, anything you do with those two apps can also be done in Terminal with the launchctl command.  But that brings another level of complexity. The command man launchctl provides the documentation.
